# Is it possible to use @JoinTable over a subclass that includes target + join fields?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, spring-data

My model (exemplified) is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE team (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
  ....
);

CREATE TABLE team_reference_persons (
  team_id INT NOT NULL,
  person_id INT NOT NULL,
  uses_telephone BOOLEAN, 
  PRIMARY KEY (team_id, person_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES team(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(id)
);
```

And my JPA defintion:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "team")
public class Team {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "team_reference_persons", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Person> teamReferencePersons;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

So far, so good, when all you need is the person list on the team. But now I need to add the `team_reference_persons.uses_telephone` property from the join table in my person domain, So I am looking for a way to keep the persons logic, while I create a new subclass.

```
private class TeamIndividual extends Person {
    boolean uses_telephone;
}
```

Then changing `List<Person>` on `Team` entity by `List<TeamIndividual>`. Is that possible someway? JPA should be indicated in such smart way that it adds the join table property to the final target entity (on both read and save).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No need to extend TeamIndividual to Person.
- Annotate TeamIndividual with @Table(name = "team_reference_persons")
- Define fields(teamId,personId,uses_telephone) inside TeamIndividual
- Annotate fields teamId and PersonId with @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn
- Add List to Team without annotation
  Try this,It will work..!!

Comment: Thanks!. But I got a problem. If I convert the join table into an entity I need a primary key for my Spring Data entity. Isn't there another tricky way with the join table in a transaparent way? Or should I do a compose Primary Key?

Comment: Use compose primary key using teamId and personId